# React Typescript Mutation calling api every time the page is clicked

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mutation

I have a simple page that calls an api to get some data and display it in a table. I use a function that uses mutation to call the api and return the data and the state of fetching the data. I use the following (pseudo) code to achieve this:

```
    export const Instances = (props: InstanceProps) => {
    const history =
        useHistory<{
            formId: number;
            rowData: any;
            formInstanceID: number;
        }>();
    const { isLoading, isError, isSuccess, data, error } = useGetFromApi('api/list', [
        `${history.location.state.formId}`,
    ]);

if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <div>
                Page Loading
            </div>
        );
    }

    if (isError) {
        return (
            <div>
                An error occurred
            </div>
        );
    }

    if (isSuccess) {
        if (data) {
            // Map data to an array for the table component
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            Display table showing data
        </div>
    );
};
```

The page calls the api successfully and displays the data in the table. The problem I have is when I click anywhere on the page or click the two buttons that are present on the page the mutation is called again and the page freezes while it fetches the data again. It doesn't remember that it's successfully loaded. How do I stop it from calling the api every time I interact with the page?

The code for the mutation function:

```
import { usePidgetIdentity } from '@workspace/utils-react';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import config from '../shared/config';

export type ApiData = {
    data: any[];
};

async function callToApi(url: string, getAccessToken: () => Promise<string>) {
    const token = await getAccessToken();

    console.log('Starting api fetch');

    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });

    console.log('Data has returned');

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw Error('An unexpected error occurred');
    }

    const apidata = await response.json();
    return { data: apidata };
}

export function useGetFromApi(url: string, parameters: string[]) {
    const { getAccessToken } = usePidgetIdentity();
    let apiUrl: string = config.FORMS_API_URL + '/' + url;

    parameters.map((parameter) => {
        apiUrl += '/' + parameter.trim();
    });

    console.log('Calling ' + apiUrl);

    return useQuery<ApiData, Error>(apiUrl, () => callToApi(apiUrl, getAccessToken));
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the mutation function ?

Comment: @Shyam I have added the function